# formatting Created_at in php for Twitter Api

Tags: php, json, twitter

Been having problems with trying to format the "created_at" to a more appropriate form. I am using the twitter api with php/json. My code is as follows:

```
foreach ($phpdata["statuses"] as $status){
            echo("<p>" . $status["text"] . "</p>");

            echo ( $status ["user"] ["created_at"] );

        }
```

trying to change it from
`Thu Aug 11 23:30:51 +0000 2011` to something like `Thu Aug 11`.

I've searched for answers but with no luck in finding a solution. Im guessing it is an easy process but im struggling to get my head around it.

Will be much appreciated if someone can solve this so I can stop pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might help. You find more reference [PHP date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
foreach ($phpdata["statuses"] as $status){
            echo "<p>" . $status["text"] . "</p>";

            echo date( 'D M y', strtotime($status ["user"] ["created_at"]) );

        }
```

Comment: You hero! I knew it was something so simple! Thankyou very much!

Comment: How would I go about adding it to


  $text = "";
  $text = "
  <img src='" . $status["user"] ["profile_image_url"] . "'/> 
  " . $status["user"]["name"] . " 
  " .  $status["user"]["screen_name"] . "
  " . $status["user"]["location"] . "
        " . $status["text"] . "
  
        ";
  
         
   echo $text;
  ;
So I can add html tags to the line of code?

Comment: Disregard that comment, I've fixed it.